# Is the following trigger code to compare IDs of same Product fields in different objects correct?

Tags: email-alert

unfortunately I couldn't find any possible workaround to this:

our client would like to get tracked every possible detail about the email sent to their students, that means, who was the recipient, who was the sender, body content of the email.

I know this can be done with the method singleMail.setSaveAsActivity(true) if you use apex.

As I would like to avoid to use too much code and send the emails via a workflow or process builder, I was wondering if what the setSaveAsActivity does, is possible with a workflow or a process via process builder.

I would appreciate your answers. This is pretty urgent as we have to finish this task soon and we don't have any developers as ressources at the moment :( (HELP NEEDED, GUYS).

Answer (score 0):

There is no code that you can use to force emails sent from the system (i.e. emails sent by automated processes). However, you have two alternatives that you can leverage.

First, you can use the [Email Logs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_logs.htm&type=0) to report on, and download, emails. It won't include the body of the email, however. If you need those details, you'll need something more comprehensive...

You can [Set Up Email Relay](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_relay.htm&language=en&type=0), which lets you route all emails sent from your org to go through a server of your choosing. You can then record those emails any way your email server allows before it is finally sent to the destination.